Encountering pixelated edges on zoom when using GDAL while MapTiler generates clear projections
I am very new to the world of GIS, weather, and meteorology.
I am developing a weather application and am trying to transform a Geotiff (0.01 x 0.01 resolution) of the entire united states into map tiles using GDAL.
I have written a simple script using these command that can get me pretty close:
#Changes the source tiff EPSG to be more easily consumable by Openlayers/Leaflet
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 -r bilinear US_highres.tiff US_highres_3857.tiff

#Prevents high resampling on lower level zooms
gdaladdo -r average US_highres_3857.tiff 2 4 8 16 32

#Generates the tiles
gdal2tiles.py --zoom=0-10 --resampling=near --tilesize=256 --processes=4 US_highres_3857.tiff output_tiles

The problem I encountering is high pixelization on max zoom in areas of differing color.

What is frustrating is I know Maptiler Engine is using GDAL, but I can't figure out  how to compress near to the file size that they can and also have smooth, unpixelated edges.
I have tried many different resampling techniques and other methods to solve the pixel problem. I can't seem to figure it out. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

The MapTiler Engine is using GDAL mainly for data reading. The data and speed optimisation technique is in the Engine itself.
With MapTiler Engine, you can process the data on more cores then just one and there is also a larger variaty of output formats, such as MBTiles, GPKG or Directory with files of course. I copared some of the tiling tools out there in my talk at FOSS4G 2023, Prizren, it may be interesting for you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1hiPoTFn1CA
If you are not open to give MapTiler Engine a try, try to use different interpolation method https://gdal.org/en/stable/programs/gdalwarp.html#cmdoption-gdalwarp-r
